# Alternate Directory name in C:\Users

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

I use SecureCRT on 2 computers. I have the configuration stored in a Dropbox folder. However this causes some problems because my username isn't the same on both machines. Is there a way, without renaming the account, to have the user directory available under the alternate name, as you would be able to do on a unix system using a symlink?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use a symlink.

```
mklink /d C:\Users\Alternate Real
```

<sup>(note: the syntax is *mklink <link> <target>* which is different from *ln -s <target> <link>*)</sup>

Symlinks are supported as of Windows Vista, and behave pretty much [the same way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363878%28VS.85%29.aspx) as in Unix, with the exception that there can be "file" symlinks (`mklink`) and "directory" symlinks (`mklink/d`).

---

Older Windows NT versions, which don't have symlinks, still support [directory junctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365006%28VS.85%29.aspx) (`mklink /j` or [`junction`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx)) – the major differences are that junctions only work with directories, and always point to an absolute path.

Both kinds of links require a NTFS filesystem.